# Thunderbird mailboxes from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: thunderbird

I need to transfer Thunderbird mailboxes from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04. How do I do this?

Comment: if you have your emails set as SMTP creating accounts in TB using SMTP server will pull them across automatically. That way they are platform independent.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea what you mean. How do I set existing emails in Thunderbird Windows 7 to SMTP creating accounts? Then how do I transfer them from Windows 7 system unit to different Ununtu 18.04 system and place them in proper location in Ubentu 18.04 system?

Comment: how are you currently accessing your emails in Win 7? Are you using a browser to access them or an email client? If the emails are still held on the email server (such as yahoo for example) then it is easy to set up TB to access your account using SMTP.

Comment: I have used same Thunderbird & Firefox profiles since XP. Originally XP only, then shared on NTFS data partition and now on ext4 data partition shared with several Ubuntu installs. I copy entire profile folder. And normally regularly houseclean so not too large. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data & https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer

Comment: Graham-on an email client on a stand-alone laptop. Have never used an email server and have no clue how to do so.;

Comment: Oldfred-Your comment seems to say simply copy contents of Windows 7 profile folder to Ubuntu 18.04, but the articles you reference make no reference to Ubuntu at all and seem to be operating from one Windows system to another Windows system. I am confused. Help.

Comment: In Ubuntu this is default location ~/.thunderbird/xxxxxxxx.default/ from first link above. Do not remember where Windows stores profile.  the ~ is your /home and . is hidden file, you can change to show hidden files. I normally have to start Thunderbird once to create new default then copy mine and edit profile.ini to use my profile not new default. I do the same for Firefox.

Comment: Think I understand. 1. Go to Windows Thunderbird Profile Folder and copy all files to USB drive. 2. Transfer files from USB drive to Ubuntu Thunderbird Profile Folder. 3, Start Thunderbird in Ubuntu. 4. You wrote at this point "copy mine and edit profile.ini".  Not sure what "copy mine" here means. Weren't all files copied to Ubuntu Thunderbird Profile earlier at Step 3 above? Also, what does "edit" mean? What is removed and what is inserted?